# java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I'll be very appreciate any help.
I'm trying to run react-native app for android:

```
npm run android
```

What i get:

```
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1174 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

    at makeError (/Users/shulman/champ/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/shulman/champ/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/shulman/champ/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/shulman/champ/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I'm working on M1 chip if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

install this two package in your project then try again to run =>

npm i jetifier

npx jetify

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. The same errors after all

Comment: npx react-native run-android --no-jetifier

Comment: use this command, hope your problem solve

Comment: The same. Did you face the same problem?

Comment: yes, in your gradle.properties add the followin line =>

Comment: android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: It didn't help. I guess smth with my version of java